# problemas con scrollRight

Tags: jquery

hola amigos estoy tratando de hacer una pasarela de imagenes, bueno lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera un div con overflow-x:sroll; , dentro del div 5 o 6 imagenes que al clikear unos botones iran pasando y luego  ocultando el scroll para luego moverlo atraves de jquery para que las imagenes se muevan tambien. hasta aqui todo bien pero  cuando trato de mover el scroll hacia la derecha no se mueve y no entiendo por que aqui les dejo mi codigo de lo que estoy haciendo ojala me puedan ayudar

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 $(".button1").click(function(){

 
     $(".cop").animate({scrollLeft:   "+=305"}, 500);
});

 $(".button2").click(function(){

     $(".cop").animate({scrollRight:  "+=305"}, 500);
    

})
})
```

```css
.cop{

 width:300px;
height:300px;
background:white;
position:relative; 
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow:hidden;

}
.corp{

 width:auto;
height:auto;

display:flex;

}
.corp img{

   margin-left:5px;
 }

.button1{

 position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}
.button2{

 position:absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
button{
background:rgba(245,225,155,0.7);
border-radius:5px;
padding:3px;
border:none;
}

button:hover{
cursor:pointer;
padding:5px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">





  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Menú Principal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>



<div style="position:relative; max-width:300px;">
<div class="cop">
<div class="corp">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
</div>





 
</div>
<button class=" mt-5 button1">LEFT</button>
<button class="mt-5 button2">RIGHT</button>
   </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TE PROPONGO LA SIGUIENTE SOLUCION guarda en una variable la posision del scroll de esta manera

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 $(".button1").click(function(){

var leftPos = $('.cop').scrollLeft();
     $(".cop").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos +305}, 500);
});

 $(".button2").click(function(){
var leftPos = $('.cop').scrollLeft();
     $(".cop").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos -305}, 500);
    
})
})
```

```css
.cop{

 width:300px;
height:300px;
background:white;
position:relative; 
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow:hidden;

}
.corp{

 width:auto;
height:auto;

display:flex;

}
.corp img{

   margin-left:5px;
 }

.button1{

 position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}
.button2{

 position:absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
button{
background:rgba(215,235,155,0.7);
border-radius:5px;
padding:3px;
border:none;
}

button:hover{
cursor:pointer;
padding:5px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">





  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Menú Principal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>



<div style="position:relative; max-width:300px;">
<div class="cop">
<div class="corp">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
<img src="newzoneg.png" width="300px" height="300px">
</div>





 
</div>
<button class=" mt-5 button1">LEFT</button>
<button class="mt-5 button2">RIGHT</button>
   </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wuao que genialidad muchas gracias @andy gibbs te lo agradesco mucho

Comment: no hay de que no olvides calificar como valida la respuesta si te fue util